# plugin wp_insert_post error 500

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую в своем плагине для WP функцию wp_insert_post() для добавления поста, как только включаю плагин выдает Ошибка сервера 500, но запись в базу записывается. 
Если закомментировать wp_insert_post(), плагин работает нормально.

```
$t = explode('wp-content',dirname(__FILE__));
        require_once($t[0].'/wp-load.php');
        require_once($t[0].'/wp-config.php');

$my_post = array(
             'post_title' => 'dsd',
             'post_content' => 'asdsd',
             'post_status' => 'draft',
             'post_author' => 1,
             'post_type' => 'post'

          );

        // Вставляем запись в базу данных
        wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в is_user_logged_in(), решил обернув в хук init . Всем спасибо)

```
add_action('init', 'create_post');
function create_post(){
      $my_post = array(
         'post_title' => 'dsd',
         'post_content' => 'asdsd',
         'post_status' => 'draft',
         'post_author' => 1,
         'post_type' => 'post'

       );

    // Вставляем запись в базу данных
    wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что логи сервера выдают? 500 обычно значит, что ошибка в коде. Возможно пустой массив приходит. Проверяй данные и  код.

Comment: Массив не пустой, в базу запись записывается.

Comment: логи покажи. Что-то явно не так

Comment: Файл error.log пуст, заполнен только access.log но в нем только соединения с сайтом.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что у вас на сервере включено логирование ошибок.

Если логирование включено, но в лог ничего не записывается, то можно прибегнуть к различного рода отладчикам. Но я бы поступил следующим образом, хоть это и топорно. Открыл бы файл wp-includes\post.php, нашел бы в нем функцию wp_insert_post и залогировал бы ее — то есть добавил бы в нее вывод в произвольный текстовый файл отладочной информации. Причем логировать начал бы с конца функции к началу.

```
function wp_insert_post( $postarr, $wp_error = false ) {
    // очищаем лог при необходимости
    //file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "");

    // указываем, что функция начала свою работу
    file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "старт\n", FILE_APPEND);

    // .................
    // пропускаем середину функции и переходим к концу
    // .................
    // логируем отдельные действия
    file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "do_action save_post\n", FILE_APPEND);
    do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_ID, $post, $update );

    /**
     * Fires once a post has been saved.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     *
     * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
     * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
     */
    file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "do_action save_post\n", FILE_APPEND);
    do_action( 'save_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );

    /**
     * Fires once a post has been saved.
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param int     $post_ID Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
     * @param bool    $update  Whether this is an existing post being updated or not.
     */
    file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "do_action wp_insert_post\n", FILE_APPEND);
    do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );

    file_put_contents("wp_insert_post_log.txt", "конец\n", FILE_APPEND);
    return $post_ID;
}
```

Затем запускаете скрипт, воспроизводите ошибку, смотрите лог. Таким образом ищете в каком месте падает программа и сужаете круг логируя производные функции, пока не найдете виновника.

Answer (score 0):

Подобное в плагине писать не нужно:

```
$t = explode('wp-content',dirname(__FILE__));
require_once($t[0].'/wp-load.php');
require_once($t[0].'/wp-config.php');
```

wp_insert_post - доступен в плагине, как любые другие функции, а повторное подключение файлов и конфига (конфиг не уместен, и если уже писать то require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php'); ) может вызвать 500